# What's the difference between a dowel pin symbol on a hole, and just a regular hole?

Tags: drafting

I noticed that sometimes I would see holes labelled like this:
[image]

but most of the times, they would be drawn "normally", like this: [image]

Why would someone use a dowel pin symbol if a regular hole means the same thing?

Comment: Are you sure the first symbol representing a dowel pin? It is usually used for referencing a datum/elevation or a specific location in a plot

Comment: On some equipment like hydraulic machinery, the pin hole tolerances are fantastically high. You disassemble a machine with a 3/4 inch pullbar and then find the stack assembled with dowel pins the size of tiny needle bearing rollers. Using a datum symbol makes sense there.